# Checking for the correct answer from an NSString in an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSMutableArray` that contains an answer to a question. The answer is stored in an `NSString`. I am trying to check wether the answer is correct or not when the user clicks the done button the keyboard.

Every time I click done, it always displays incorrect when in fact, the answer is correct.

I am note sure what I am doing wrong.

I even do an `NSLog` and the `NSLog` returns the valid answer. Is there something wrong in the if statements?

## Code:

```
- (IBAction)checkAnswer:(UITextField *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"The question's answer for the question you selected is %@", [selectedQuestion questionAnswer]);

        if (answerField.text == [selectedQuestion questionAnswer])
        {
            // Show the correct label
            [correctLabel setHidden:NO];
            correctLabel.text = @"Correct!";
            correctLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];

        }
        if (answerField.text != [selectedQuestion questionAnswer])
        {
            [correctLabel setHidden:NO];
            correctLabel.text = @"Incorrect";
            correctLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        }

        // answerField.text = @"";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use the methode isEqualToString of NSString Class

```
- (IBAction)checkAnswer:(UITextField *)sender
{


NSLog(@"The question's answer for the question you selected is %@", [selectedQuestion questionAnswer]);

    if ([answerField.text isEqualToString:[selectedQuestion questionAnswer]])
    {
        // Show the correct label
        [correctLabel setHidden:NO];
        correctLabel.text = @"Correct!";
        correctLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    }
    if (answerField.text != [selectedQuestion questionAnswer])
    {
        [correctLabel setHidden:NO];
        correctLabel.text = @"Incorrect";
        correctLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    // answerField.text = @"";
```

}

Comment: Thanks, wow I feel stupid. I forgot about that statement. I will accept your answer in 8 minutes, it won't let me b/c I just accepted an old answer.